# Trouble with generating random outcomes

Tags: python

I am having trouble generating random outcomes for my simple Python blackjack game.

It seems to only update the results list by one when I specify that the loop should run 100 times.

```
import random

def hand_tallyer(hand):
    total=0
    aces=0
    for card in hand:
        if card in ['J', 'Q', 'K']:
            total+=10
        elif card=='A':
            aces+=1
        else:
            total+=int(card)

    total+=aces

    while total+10 < 21 and aces > 0:
        total+=10
        aces-=1
    return total


def hand_checker(hand1, hand2):
    tot1=hand_tallyer(hand1)
    tot2=hand_tallyer(hand2)
    if tot1 <= 21 and (tot1>tot2 or tot2>21):
        results[0]+=1
    else:
        results[1]+=1

hands=[random.randint(0,10), 'J', 'K', 'Q', 'A']
hands2=[random.randint(0,10), 'J', 'K', 'Q', 'A']
hands3=[random.randint(0,10), 'J', 'K', 'Q', 'A']
hands4=[random.randint(0,10), 'J', 'K', 'Q', 'A']


def run_it(x):
     for i in range(x):
        results=[0,0]
        first=''
        second=''
        first=str(random.choice(hands))+str(random.choice(hands2))
        second=str(random.choice(hands3))+str(random.choice(hands4))
        return hand_checker(first,second)
print(results)

run_it(100)
```

Am I missing the order of commands here? Should the results list be placed elsewhere?

Comment: Python is a whitespace-sensitive language. Can you fix your question so the indentation is correct?

Comment: Could you expand a little on the specific problem, too? What is your understanding of the logic of this code? It doesn't make sense to me, for example, that `hands` contains only one number between 0 and 10 inclusive (zero doesn't exist in a pack of cards, and one is the same as the ace) plus all four face cards. What you've called a "hand" seems more like (some of) a *suit*.

Comment: `second==str(random.choice(hands3))+str(random.choice(hands4))` will compare `second` and the right-hand side for equality. If you didn't have `second=''` before this line, you'd get an error

Comment: hands and hands2 and hands3 and hands4 contain only 1 number and the J, Q, K. Also your indentation is incorrect and you never imported random or defined hand_tallyer

Comment: I have updated the code, thank you.

Comment: `first==str(...)` - These statements in `run_it` will have no effect because you are checking for equality instead of assigning.  So you end up passing empty strings to `hand_checker`.